# Dynamically call a function on child on attr src in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to call a function on attr src but failing. Here is what i have tried.

```
function FavoriteViewModel() {
    var self = this

    self.FavoriteProfiles   =   ko.observableArray([])

    self.getRating  =   function(Rating){
        //here i want conditions and concat image path
        return does nothing here
    }

    self.LoadData   =   function(){
        //run ajax and put its result in self.FavoriteProfiles
        self.FavoriteProfiles(Result)
    }   

    self.LoadData()
}
```

When i run ajax this brings this result. Results are multiple i am only posting single object to understand

```
ProfileId   20
Age         21
Gender      "F"
Rating      4
```

And im binding data like this

```
<div id="favorite-related-profiles" data-bind="foreach:FavoriteProfiles">
<article class="prfl_box">
    <p>
        <span id="favorite-related-age" data-bind="text:Age"></span>               
        <span id="favorite-related-gender" data-bind="text:Gender"></span>               
        <br>
        <img id="favorite-related-rating" class="pro_rating" src="" data-bind="attr:{src:Rating}">
    </p>
</article>
</div>
```

When i try this binding like this

```
<img id="favorite-related-rating" class="pro_rating" src="" data-bind="attr:{src:$root.getRating.bind($data,Rating)}">
```

I get this in src

```
src="function () { [native code] }"
```

How can i dynamically generate src attribute.
Note i need to display image. Images are named 4rating.png , 5rating.png , default.png.
I want to check if rating is 4 assing 4rating in src attribute. How can i do this.

Comment: Check out computed observable http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, their are few ways to do it. Now if I have understood your question then you need to need to have src attribute as `4rating.png` , `5rating.png` and so on depending on the Rating value as 4,5 respectively.

If this is the scenario the look into this [**DEMO - A dirty way**](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/AeZ2W/)

Now, lets get it to function as per your code:-

You can look into [**DEMO2- Proper way**](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/AeZ2W/60/). If you inspect element and see yopu'll find the HTML markup as below:-

```
<td data-bind="attr:{src: $root.getRating($data)}" src="4rating.png">
            </td>
```

Hope it helps.

Edited:-

Just a suggestion, when you are using Knockout Model's then you can keep your Model Seperate. Keep your flow simple, it will be more Extensible.
I'll share how I learn to code with knockout using Revealing Module Pattern **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/K5sKc/)**.

Create your View Model as simple as this:-

```
function FavoriteViewModel(data) {
    var self = this

    self.ProfileId = data.ProfileId;//Do some exception handling
    self.Age = data.Age;//Do some exception handling
    self.Gender = data.Gender;//Do some exception handling
    self.Rating = data.Rating;//Do some exception handling
    self.RatingExtended = data.Rating + "rating.png"; //Some random stuff

}
```

Create a variable that will hold your Favorite Array and will be `data-bind` to HTML.

```
var FavoriteProfiles = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Lastly, AJAX call to get the data and assign it to your `FavoriteProfiles` .

```
var ajaxdata = DummyAjaxCall(); //get all profiles

        $.each(ajaxdata, function (index, value) {
            FavoriteProfiles.push(new FavoriteViewModel(value)); //Create a Model
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it really helps. before your answer i alos found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13154329/binding-image-src-as-expression-in-knockout)

Comment: the final example you posted i have tried this already. Instead of concating in Rating Extended i used computed observable but it was not working.

Comment: @raheelshan It should be working for you, just to cross verify [Demo3 with Computed Observables](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/K5sKc/17/) :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your data-bind to:

```
data-bind="attr:{src:$root.getRating.bind($data,Rating)}"
```

All that has changed is I have taken the `''` from around the function call since by doing that you are essentially setting the src to the function as a string.

Edit: try removing the bind on the function

```
data-bind="attr:{src:$root.getRating($data,Rating)}"
```

Comment: Thanks i have already tried it but that's not working. But by the way have you tested and is it working?

Comment: I've not tried your example but that is the correct way of doing it.  When debugging your code does the getRating function actually get hit?